# selectMenu jQuery UI not working on bootstrap 5 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this great source over here https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render for customizing the select tag with icons.

But when I add this on modal using Bootstrap v5.0. It doesn't seem to work and icons are disappearing.

I tried using this:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h2>Selectmenu with custom icon images</h2>
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="filesB">Select a podcast:</label>
                    <select name="filesB" id="filesB">
                        <option value="mypodcast" data-class="podcast">John Resig Podcast</option>
                        <option value="myvideo" data-class="video">Scott Gonz&#xE1;lez Video</option>
                        <option value="myrss" data-class="rss">jQuery RSS XML</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't seem to render the selectMenu widget.

Any chance to help anyone?

Comment: do you initialize it when the modal is rendered? Or before?